# Condense down jQuery on click events

Tags: jquery, html

This feature works fine, but it is an eye sore. the CSS is initially hiding all but the first pie-1 class but I didn't include that part as it's not that important.  I took some html out just to make it look simpler. As you can see, the jQuery is redundant and I am sure there is a better way to do this but I'm not sure how to clean this JS up..

```js
$(".committed").addClass("committed-active");
$(".committed").on("click", function() {
  $(".pie-1").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".committed").addClass("committed-active");
  $(".pie-2, .pie-3, .pie-4, .pie-5").hide();
  $(".inclined").removeClass("inclined-active");
  $(".equipped").removeClass("equipped-active");
  $(".empowered").removeClass("empowered-active");
  $(".consent").removeClass("consent-active");
});
$(".inclined").on("click", function() {
  $(".pie-2").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".inclined").addClass("inclined-active");
  $(".pie-1, .pie-3, .pie-4, .pie-5").hide();
  $(".committed").removeClass("committed-active");
  $(".equipped").removeClass("equipped-active");
  $(".empowered").removeClass("empowered-active");
  $(".consent").removeClass("consent-active");
});
$(".equipped").on("click", function() {
  $(".pie-3").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".equipped").addClass("equipped-active");
  $(".pie-2, .pie-1, .pie-4, .pie-5").hide();
  $(".inclined").removeClass("inclined-active");
  $(".committed").removeClass("committed-active");
  $(".empowered").removeClass("empowered-active");
  $(".consent").removeClass("consent-active");
});
$(".empowered").on("click", function() {
  $(".pie-4").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".empowered").addClass("empowered-active");
  $(".pie-3, .pie-2, .pie-1, .pie-5").hide();
  $(".inclined").removeClass("inclined-active");
  $(".equipped").removeClass("equipped-active");
  $(".committed").removeClass("committed-active");
  $(".consent").removeClass("consent-active");
});
$(".consent").on("click", function() {
  $(".pie-5").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".consent").addClass("consent-active");
  $(".pie-2, .pie-3, .pie-4, .pie-1").hide();
  $(".inclined").removeClass("inclined-active");
  $(".equipped").removeClass("equipped-active");
  $(".empowered").removeClass("empowered-active");
  $(".committed").removeClass("committed-active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex-align-center-left p-0">
    <label class="interactive-text p-3 committed">Slide 1
      <input name="interactive-1" type="radio" class="text-dark committed interactive-text">
     </label>
    <label class="interactive-text p-3 inclined">Slide 2
      <input name="interactive-1" type="radio" class="text-dark inclined interactive-text">
     </label>
    <label class="interactive-text p-3 equipped">Slide 3
      <input name="interactive-1" type="radio" class="text-dark equipped interactive-text">
     </label>
    <label class="interactive-text p-3 empowered">Slide 4
      <input name="interactive-1" type="radio" class="text-dark empowered interactive-text">
     </label>
    <label class="interactive-text p-3 consent">Slide 5
      <input name="interactive-1" type="radio" class="text-dark consent interactive-text">
     </label>
  </div>
  <!-- slide 1 -->
  <div class="col-lg-8 bg-lightgray round pie-1">
    <h4 class="pie-header blue mb-3">slide 1</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pie">
        <img src="images/pie-24.svg" alt="Donut chart for Feel More Committed section">
      </div>
      <div class="pie-aside d-flex-center-center">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Slide 2 -->
  <div class="col-lg-8 bg-lightgray round pie-2">
    <h4 class="pie-header purple mb-3">slide 2</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pie">
        <img src="images/pie-25.svg" alt="Donut chart for Feel More Committed section">
      </div>
      <div class="pie-aside d-flex-center-center">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Slide 3 -->
  <div class="col-lg-8 bg-lightgray round pie-3">
    <h4 class="pie-header teal mb-3">slide 3</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pie">
        <img src="images/pie-26.svg" alt="Donut chart for Feel More Committed section">
      </div>
      <div class="pie-aside d-flex-center-center">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Slide 4 -->
  <div class="col-lg-8 bg-lightgray round pie-4">
    <h4 class="pie-header red mb-3">slide 4</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pie">
        <img src="images/pie-27.svg" alt="Donut chart for Feel More Committed section">
      </div>
      <div class="pie-aside d-flex-center-center">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Slide 5 -->
  <div class="col-lg-8 bg-lightgray round pie-5">
    <h4 class="pie-header black mb-3">slide 5
    </h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="pie">
        <img src="images/pie-28.svg" alt="Donut chart for Feel More Committed section">
      </div>
      <div class="pie-aside d-flex-center-center">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not create a method and then just call the method with your 11 string params to simplify the js?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. What method would I have to create?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function similar to the following below.

```
function showOnClick(classToShow, classToFadeIn) {
         // all initializations
         var classesToShow = ["committed", "inclined", "equipped", "empowered", "consent"];
         var classesToFade = ".pie-1, .pie-2, .pie-3, .pie-4, .pie-5";

         // find the index of the class
         var indexOfClassToShow = classesToShow.indexOf(classToShow);
         // remove it from the array
        classesToShow.splice(indexOfClassToShow, 1);

       // remove the fade class - might not work for all cases and might be a better way to do it
       classesToFade = classesToFade.replace("." + classToFade, "").replace(", , ", ", ");

        // your repetitive code in one function
        $("." + classToShow).on("click", function(){
              $("." + classToFade).fadeIn("slow");
              $("." + classToShow).addClass(classToShow + "-active");
              $(classesToFade).hide();
                  $.each(classesToShow, function( index, value ) {
                      $("." + value).removeClass(value + "-active");
                  });
       });}
```

I apologize my JS/jQuery is a little rusty and I haven't tested this so it will need some adjusting but the idea is there. And you can call it like this

```
showOnClick("committed", "pie-1");
showOnClick("inclined", "pie-2");
showOnClick("equipped", "pie-3");
showOnClick("empowered", "pie-4");
showOnClick("consent", "pie-5");
```